# CRM Dynamics Import Organization Error During Upgrade

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I have an issue with CRM, I am attempting to upgrade from CRM 2013 to CRM 2015, this is a migration upgrade, I installed SQL on a new server and also have a designated server for the 2015 CRM server, I installed CRM 2015, did all the database backups and restore to the new SQL server, upon import of those organization in the new CRM 2015 app box, using deployment manager I get the following error below:

> at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ImportOrganizationInstaller.ImportAndUpgrade(OrganizationInfo
>   organizationInfo) ---> System.Exception: Error.ActionFailed
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.UpgradeDatabaseAction --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: There
>   is no active transaction. This error is usually caused by custom
>   plug-ins that ignore errors from service calls and continue processing

I have deactivated the plugin steps in the organization before I backup them up, what does this mean, should I delete/remove the plugins first, please assist.

Comment: You don't have to delete remove the plugin assembly. Although I have not encountered this very issue during one of our recent upgrades, it looks like what almost everybody else who encountered the issue ended up doing was to look at activity feeds plugin. Did you happen to try disabling activity feeds plugin step?

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I tried disabling the plugin steps but still error occurs after I backup and restore again, then try to import.

Comment: As you are on-prem, turn on tracing, you will more than likely find the cause of the issue.